# Python label script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser

I'm trying to make a label expression using Python (open to using VBscript or Jscript as well) and I just cannot get the result I want...

I have 2 columns within my attribute table and I want them stacked like a fraction, where column A is separated from Column B by an EM-dash.

The current code I am using is... [numerator] + \n (trying to have em dash here) \n [denominator]. If I put a regular dash, no problem, but em-dash it gives me an error.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is likely an encoding/Unicode issue.  More details on the string assembly syntax are needed. Using a `u""` string with `.format()` is highly recommended.